# Python SyntaxError vs TypeError for repeated keyword arguments

Tags: python, error-handling, syntax-error, typeerror

Python obviously does not allow the same keyword to appear multiple times in function arguments. Here are 2 code samples to show that point:

```
def foo(a=None, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Calling this code to produce a `SyntaxError`:

```
>>> # Example 1
>>> foo(a=1, a=1)
File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated
```

Calling this code to produce a `TypeError`:

```
>>> # Example 2
>>> foo(1, a=123)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() got multiple values for argument 'a'
```

Intuitively, I would expect both examples to raise `SyntaxErrors`.

**Why does the first method produce a `SyntaxError` while the second method produces a `TypeError`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Errors#:%7E:text=Syntax%20errors%20are%20the%20most,understand%20a%20line%20of%20code.&text=In%20IDLE%2C%20it%20will%20highlight,incorrect%20indentation%2C%20or%20incorrect%20arguments.):

> Syntax errors are the most basic type of error. They arise when the Python parser is unable to understand a line of code.

So `foo(a=1, a=1)` is an invalid python code, while `foo(1, a=123)` by itself **without escope context** is a valid python code, thus syntax error is not raised. However, after the code gets parsed, the interpretation of it given the **current context** fails because the signature of the `foo` function defined before confuses the interpreter since you have multiple definitions for `a`.

I can say that it's not a `KeyError` because you don't have an explicitly dictionary involved. You are passing key words arguments but a dictionary was never created and KeyError is [Raised when a mapping (dictionary) key is not found in the set of existing keys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError). Additionally, from the [documentation you linked](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) in the comment, I would say that it's a `TypeError` because it involves the parsing of the arguments in a function call. But I'm not so sure. Nevertheless, the `RuntimeError` is a generic exception when no one of the other exceptions fit but the interpreter detected an error.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I think it explains a lot about the `SyntaxError`. Do you have any additional insights on why a `TypeError` is raised for the second case as opposed to `KeyError`, `RuntimeError` or any other Exception? I'd also like to mention that `SyntaxError` can be produced from `import`, `exec`, and `eval` as well (See https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html)

Comment: @Joe I added an additional paragraph trying to answer your additional doubts.